# How to capture variable length lists with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have lists embedded in unrelated text that look like this:

```
Unrelated TextUnrelated TextUnrelated Text

Study Durations(HH:MM) Time 
Total 04:00 
Upright 02:08 
Supine 01:49 
Other  03:10 
More Other 12:34

Unrelated TextUnrelated TextUnrelated TextUnrelated TextUnrelated TextUnrelated TextUnrelated TextUnrelated TextUnrelated TextUnrelated Text

Study Durations(HH:MM) Time 
Total 24:00 
Upright 12:18 
Supine 11:42 
PostPr  n/a
```

I would like to capture the groups to get this:

Example 1 output

```
Study Durations(HH:MM) Time 
Total 04:00 
Upright 02:08 
Supine 01:49 
Other  03:10 
More Other 12:34
```

Example 2 output

```
Study Durations(HH:MM) Time 
Total 24:00 
Upright 12:18 
Supine 11:42 
PostPr  n/a
```

I have tried the following regex

```
Pattern Total_pattern = Pattern.compile("Study Durations\\(HH:MM\\) Time\\s*(?:\\n[A-Za-z]+\\s+(?:\\d+(?::\\d+)?|n/a))",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

but I only get

```
Study Durations(HH:MM) Time 
Total 04:00 


Study Durations(HH:MM) Time 
Total 24:00
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to read line by line, and store the block of lines from the `Study Durations` marker until the next empty line ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with a lookahead:

```
Study Durations\(HH:MM\) Time.*?(?=\n\n|\z)
```

Make sure to use `DOTALL` modifier in order to match across the lines.

Java pattern:

```
Pattern Total_pattern = Pattern.compile(
     "Study Durations\\(HH:MM\\) Time.*?(?=\\n\\n|\\z)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ7oC4/1)